# The following error occurred while using py2exe

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

python setup.py py2exe

The following error occurred while using py2exe.

The source code for setup.py:

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['python.py'])
```

I'm trying to make python.py exe.

the mistake of this moment:

```
E:\ajil\Program\Query>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['python.py'])
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Users\dashzeveg.b\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: The last Python 3-compatible version of `py2exe` was for Python 3.4, released in 2014. Look at `pyinstaller` if you want to construct executables from Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pyinstaller that will help you for this. [pyinstaller](https://sites.google.com/view/way2learnings/programming-tools/python-to-executable/pyinstaller)

```
pip install PyInstaller 

pyinstaller <options> <ScriptName.py>

pyinstaller myscript.py # Normal Usage
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py # To create single executable
```

Comment: Dear Dhamodharan, Thank you. I did it well